# Share page via url in safe way?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My index.php is making ajax post calls to ajax.php and getting echoed json as result, then parsed and displayed with js. So it is POST. I want to be able to share that result, via link like `mydomain/index.php?q=foo&q1=foo1`.

Here is basic pseudo-code scenario that isn't safe, I want suggestion how to achieve this in safe manner?

```
//index.php
//js
$.post('ajax.php', querystring, function(){

    collect_result = result;
});

//ajax.php
parse($_POST);
echo json_encode(result);

// I want to be able to share result in way

http://.../index.php?q=foo&q1=foo1

//index.php

if(!empty($_GET['q]))
   $querystr = http_build_query($_GET, '', '&');

<div id="div1" style="display:none"><?php echo $querystr; ?></div>

//then get it wuth jquery and make ajax.post()


$.post('ajax.php', $('#div1').html(), function(){

    collect_result = result;
});


//BUT THEN USER IS ABLE TO DIRECT INJECT CODE INTO MY HTML (XSS)
//IS THERE SAFE WAY TO DO THIS SHARING VIA LINK???
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you refer to this, but as mentioned in w3schools:

The htmlspecialchars() function converts special characters to HTML entities. This means that it will replace HTML characters like < and > with < and >. This prevents attackers from exploiting the code by injecting HTML or Javascript code (Cross-site Scripting attacks) in forms.

Answer (score 1):

I work with ajax on a daily basis dealing with this dilema pretty often. There are times where I have to even put password and user in a url. When sensitive data gets visible like that, I encrypt the variables. I use a php encryption method with a special key, and I decode it when I receive the variable by POST. If your are interested in this method you can look at the cbc encryption/decryption. I am sure there are others but cbc seems to be the safest. (be sure to enable the mcrypt in the php).